# Bootstrap 5 sticky-top not working when element is in a container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

My `<nav>` is `.sticky-top` but it scrolls out of view, and doesn't stick to the top of the viewport when scrolling:

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    body {
      height: 200vh;
      /* Just to force scrolling for this example */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div><!-- example container -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div><!-- /example container -->

  <main>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to remove the outer container, so that the `.sticky-top` element is a child of the `<body>` tag, or move `.sticky-top` to the containing element (in this case the `<div>`).

This does not seem to be an issue with `.fixed-top`.